# Oracle Data can not set Time on gregorian calendar

Tags: java, oracle

I create java method which I load to oracle database and run it from plsql code.

```
public static int getSomethink(Integer multiplicity, DATE startDate);
```

This method takes `oracle.sql.DATE startDate`.

When I want to:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(startDate);
```

I have an error which say method `setTime(Date)` accept normal `Date`, not `oracle.sql.DATE`.
So here is my questions:

How to create conversion between `java.util.Date` and `oracle.sql.DATE`?
Do you have any others ideas which can solve this issue?

Comment: Please take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/DATE.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply call [`dateValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/sql/DATE.html#dateValue()) on `startDate` to convert internal Oracle Date to a Java Date.

Something like:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(startDate.dateValue());
```